# WS02: Invoking external weather SOAP webservice from ESB

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to use WSO2 ESB (version 4.8.1) to invoke externally hosted SOAP web services. To try it out I was using a public web service for weather information (http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL), more specifically the GetWeatherInformation operation.

I have successfully consumed the web service using the soapUI tool.

I am a newcomer to SOAP and ESB,  so I tried to follow a number of blog entries, but I keep on getting errors. I tried using proxy service, payload factory and send but still didn't manage. Can somebody please help me with setting this up?

Thanks

Comment: we need to know about the errors you get in order to help you : could you show us the stack traces and a copy of your proxy configuration (proxy service inside WSO2 ESB) ?

Comment: I actually managed to use a proxy but had to publish the WSDL as follows: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="testws3"
       transports="http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx" format="soap12"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>

Comment: Can I do something similar but from an API instead of proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here come a sample API to invoke GetWeatherInformation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="testws3api"
     context="/testws3api">
   <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/GetWeatherInformation">
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <GetWeatherInformation xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"/>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

You just have to send a GET http request to http://esb.hostname:8280/testws3api/GetWeatherInformation (use SoapUI or type this address in your internet browser) and you will get back the XML response from the Weather WS

Answer (score 0):

It works with this proxy conf deployed in WSO2 ESB v4.8.1 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="testws3"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <target>
      <endpoint>
         <wsdl service="Weather"
               port="WeatherSoap12"
               uri="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL"/>
      </endpoint>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL"/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: I want to specifically invoke the GetWeatherInformation action through an API but I'm not managing. How can I do that?